# Angular Dynamic Form Validations - Either or custom validation

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8

I need to write  a custom validation,

1. If nationality is 1 then passport is mandatory - this had done.
2. If nationality is 2 then either civilId or passport number is mandatory - **needed solution for this**

Point 2 how can i achieve.

So that error message should display in html like this

```
<span *ngIf="form.get('passportNo').errors" class="tooltiptext">{{' passportNo is required'}}</span>

this.form = this.fb.group({
      civilId: [""],
      nationality: [""]
      passportNo: [""],

})

  setExpatValidators() {
    const passportNo = this.form.get('passportNo');
    this.form.get('nationality').valueChanges
    .subscribe(nationality => {
          if(nationality ==  1){
        passportNo.setValidators([Validators.required]);
      }
  });
 }

submitForm(){
 if (!this.form.valid) {
 return;
}
```

Suggest if there any other way

Comment: what you are doing is the correct way

Comment: @yash either..... or how can I achieve ?

Comment: ah sorry i didnt know you have a problem with second one, i will show you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom validator for your form group:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    civilId: [""],
    nationality: [""],
    passportNo: [""]
  });
  this.form.setValidators(this.formValidator());
}

formValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
    const nationality = group.controls.nationality;
    const passportNo = group.controls.passportNo;
    const civilId = group.controls.civilId;
    let errors = null;

    if (nationality.value === 1 && !passportNo.value) {
      errors = { passportNoRequired: true };
    }
    if (nationality.value === 2 && !passportNo.value && !civilId.value) {
      errors = { passportNoOrCivilIdRequired: true };
    }
    return errors;
  };
}
```

And validate again your form:

```html
<span *ngIf="form.errors && form.errors.passportNoOrCivilIdRequired" class="tooltiptext">passportNo or Civil Id is required</span>
```

**Working Demo**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-validations-ng?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform1%2Fform1.component.ts